# Code generation for iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, code-generation, scaffolding

I'm searching for a framework to create apps for both Android and iOS from one codebase. I'm aware of Appcelarator and PhoneGap etc. However I need a different kind of product. I'm not sure if it exists. I can't find it here or on google.

We are a team of Android and iOS developers and aren't afraid to build natively. What I want is a tool to help me jumpstart development. Preferably a tool where I can create the basic UI and Models and generate native code to use as basis for further development.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)??

**iOS**

- Note: Make sure you following the instructions on the MonoTouch website re installation
- Development tools (Free): XCode + Interface Builder (http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios)
- MonoTouch ($399USD):  http://monotouch.net/
- Register for developer program/app store ($99USD): Register

**Android**

- Note: Make sure you following the instructions on the MonoDroid website re installation
- Development tools (Free): Java JDK, Android SDK
- MonoDroid (public beta): monodroid-download
- Register for developer program/market ($25USD): Register

Don’t forget for the iOS component you’re going to need to go buy a Mac to use.

Comment: I'm already an Android and iOS developer. We already have all the hardware and licenses. On this page (http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/deep_dive/mtouch) it states that mono can compile to source code. (Compile to source code, for integration with X-Code.) but examples and documentation is missing. Do you have experience with it?

Comment: No, sorry, I only have some experience developing with "Mono for Android". I've never make nothing for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at LiveCode 5 from RunRev.

http://www.runrev.com/

Comment: Livecode looks to me as a tool to create cross-platform apps. That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a tool to generate Objective C and Java code as a base for further app development. Do you have experience with livecode and this scenario?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've just looked at it with a view to cross platform deployment. You're correct in that it has it's own language and as far as I'm aware doesn't generate objc or Java

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out DAPP? I like it quite a bit.

http://dapp.kerofrog.com.au/

Comment: Good suggestion.  Though, DAPP is only iOS.  It would be really interesting to see an Android tool like DAPP.  Doesn't really do Object "Models"; but does basic UI and is loaded with the standard iOS UI controls seems like a good jump start to me (but I just started to use it and can't speak to the quality of the code it generates as of yet).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can Generate the code for both Android/ios and many more languages  using the Tool ***Swagger***

Please Check the tool,this tool gives the basic UI and Models and generate native code to  just like your Requirement.
But You have to right the Swaggger Specification file(it will be on Json or Yaml) for that. And after Writing Swagger Specification file You can downlaod the code for Android/ios and other language as well. So kindly follow the document of swagger. You will get clear idea about that.

Here i list down usefull links of swagger :

> https://swagger.io/
>
> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen
>
> https://editor.swagger.io/
>
> https://swagger.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called Genexus for Smart Devices, which is a code generator that supports iOS, Android, Blackberry and Windows 8.

However, you need to learn the tool, and I've found it useful only for simple CRUD apps. It does enable extremely fast development of said apps, it's a good fit for simple LOB apps. I've tried it and deployed to Android (haven't tested on iOS or other platforms).

http://www.genexus.com/SD/mobile-application-development?en

If you're experienced with iOS and Android, you'll probably get frustrated though (and I'm sure the code it generates isn't pretty).

I've used the generator for desktop and web .NET and Java, and works reasonably well (with those caveats), so I'm sure the Smart Devices generator will continue evolving.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Flutter, from [their docs](https://flutter.dev):

```
Flutter transforms the app development process. Build, test, and deploy beautiful mobile, web, desktop, and embedded apps from a single codebase.
```